# How can I allow users to write C# lambda in config and load them dynamically

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I have a set of data which is not particularly clean, and I have written functions for LINQ queries that filter out what I think is unnecessary data. I have written these as lambdas. However I would like to be able to put the lambdas in the .config file so they can be fiddled with without having to recompile the entire application. I was sure that this could be done, and I have managed to find some code online which takes C# source code and compiles it:

```
internal static class DynamicDelegates
{
    internal static Assembly CompileAssembly(string source)
    {
        var compilerParameters = new CompilerParameters()
        {

            GenerateExecutable = false,
            GenerateInMemory = true,
            ReferencedAssemblies =
            {
                "System.Core.dll", // needed for linq + expressions to compile
                "PatchDataLibrary.dll" // A dependency on the main application.
            },
        };

        var providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        providerOptions.Add("CompilerVersion", "v4.5.2");
        var compileProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions);
        var results = compileProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParameters, source);
        if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("{0} errors during compilation of rules", results.Errors.Count);
            foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(error.ErrorText);
            }
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Broken rules configuration, please fix");
        }
        var assembly = results.CompiledAssembly;
        return assembly;
    }
}
```

The code following leverages this to return the delegate (ReleaseType.ProductBelongs):

```
namespace Shibboleth.ReleaseHandoverUtility.Configuration
{
    internal class ProductBelongsDelegateElement : ConfigurationElement
    {
    private const string _classTemplate = @"
        using System;
        using System.Linq.Expressions;
        using PatchDataLibrary.Models.ReleaseModel;

        namespace Shibboleth.ReleaseHandoverUtility
        {{
        public static class ProductBelongsLib
        {{
            public static Shibboleth.ReleaseHandoverUtility.ReleaseType.ProductBelongs ProductBelongs {{ get {{ return {0}; }} }}
        }}
        }}
    ";

    private ProductBelongs _value;

    protected override void DeserializeElement(XmlReader reader, bool serializeCollectionKey)
    {
        string value = (reader.ReadElementContentAsString());

        var tempAssembly = DynamicDelegates.CompileAssembly(string.Format(_classTemplate, value));
        var type = tempAssembly.GetTypes().Single();
        var property = type.GetRuntimeProperties().Single();
        var propertyValue = property.GetValue(null, null);
        _value = (ProductBelongs)propertyValue;
    }

    public ProductBelongs Value { get { return _value; } }
}
```

The problem is that I am targeting Framework 4.5.2, but when it compiles the code, I get the exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Compiler executable file csc.exe cannot be found.
```

Looking online, it seems that this is because this is used to construct the path, and v4.5.2 is in the v4.0 path. Fair enough, so I change:

```
    providerOptions.Add("CompilerVersion", "v4.5.2");
```

to

```
    providerOptions.Add("CompilerVersion", "v4.0");
```

This time I get an error in the errors collection of the compiler:

[0] = {c:\Users\Mark.Bertenshaw\AppData\Local\Temp\nyposo3b.0.cs(10,74) : error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ReleaseType' does not exist in the namespace 'Shibboleth.ReleaseHandoverUtility' (are you missing an assembly reference?)}

Taking the code that causes this compilation error and putting it into a new project for framework v4.5.2 doesn't get an error. However, when as an experiment I change it to v4.0 I reproduce the error.

So can anyone suggest how I can force the framework to be 4.5.2? Or maybe there is an alternative way of doing this? Ideally, this doesn't involve downloading extra compilers and scripting frameworks.

Comment: You need to provide the full path to `PatchDataLibrary.dll`.

Comment: Try installing `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` nuget package. Then it should compile with Roslyn compiler.

Comment: @leppie Thanks - that was the problem. System.core presumably works because it is a special case.

Comment: @Evk - I was hoping that I wouldn't require a further download. Anyway, the good news is that thanks to leppie I got it working,